# ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython==7.17.0

Tags: python, heroku, pip, ipython

I uploaded a Python app to Heroku. In my `requirements.txt` file I have a line for `ipython==7.17.0` but Heroku seems unable to retrieve it, I don't understand why this might happen because I'm able to download that `ipython` version on my machine.

The complete error thrown is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython==7.17.0 (from -r /tmp/build_76afe907/requirements.txt (line 32)) (from versions: 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 4.0.0b1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.0rc1, 4.1.0rc2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 5.0.0b1, 5.0.0b2, 5.0.0b3, 5.0.0b4, 5.0.0rc1, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.9.0, 5.10.0, 6.0.0rc1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.5.0, 7.0.0b1, 7.0.0rc1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.6.1, 7.7.0, 7.8.0, 7.9.0, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 7.10.2, 7.11.0, 7.11.1, 7.12.0, 7.13.0, 7.14.0, 7.15.0, 7.16.0, 7.16.1)        
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython==7.17.0 (from -r /tmp/build_76afe907/requirements.txt (line 32))
```

Comment: "*seems unable to retrieve it*" is too broad. Can we see the full text of the error message?

Comment: @phd, it's pretty much what the title says, but I've updated the description with the full output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last allowed version is [7.16.1](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/7.16.1/), that means you use Python 3.6.

[7.17](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/7.17.0/) requires Python 3.7+.